# How do I change an id to a slug for the URL using React Router DOM

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I'm using an API where I can search using the post id. How do I change the link to a slug I created. Ex instead of /posts/1, it'll become posts/slugtitle

Post.js

```js
componentDidMount() {
  const { match: { params } } = this.props;
  axios
    .get(`/api/posts/${params.postId}`)
    .then(response => {
      console.log(response);
      this.setState({ post: response.data });
    })
    .catch(error => console.log(error));
}
```

Routes.js

```js
<Route path={"/post/:postId"}  strict component={PostShow} />
```

Also, what's the easiest way to redirect if there is no post with the id that is searched?

Comment: Where is the slug coming from? Your response from axios?

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand what you want to achieve. To redirect, you can use the `history` object that will be present in the `PostShow` props. `this.props.history.push('/somepath');` or `this.props.history.replace('/somepath');`

Comment: Yes, the slug is in the response from axios.

Answer (score 0):

change something in your code , you have to know , witch param are you pass init , maybe you want to pass title , or id , i give you and example , 
what we need , is a state to know we are title or id , 
so add this state :

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        passTitle: false,
        title:"",
        id:0
    }
}
```

now you have to change this state when click on title , ( imagine that , when user click on title , change path , for title , otherwise , change path on id :

```
handleTitleClick=(title)=>{
   this.setState({title:title,passTitle:true});
}

handleNotTitleClick=(id)=>{
   this.setState({id:id,passTitle:false});
}
```

change your componentDidMount into a function :

```
runPost=()=>{
   const { match: { params } } = this.props;
     const {passTitle,title,id}=this.state
     axios
        .get(`/api/posts/${passTitle?title:id}`)
        .then(response => {
          console.log(response);
          this.setState({ post: response.data });
        })
         .catch(error => console.log(error));
   }
```

then run it after this.setState like it :

```
handleTitleClick=(title)=>{
   this.setState({title:title,passTitle:true},()=>{this.runPost()});
}

handleNotTitleClick=(id)=>{
   this.setState({id:id,passTitle:false},()=>{this.runPost()});
}
```